# Rails 4 How to load image into database as blob

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I looked around a lot on the web. I think Paperclip may be my best hope. But I don't know how to use it to upload an image file into MySQL database from Rails 4. 
Yes I know loading it into a folder is better but I need to load it into a database. 
So, if you can help me out it will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Why put the image in the database? There's simply never a reason

Comment: Its the requirement of the project. I know uploading it to a folder would be better.

Comment: Then disregard the answer saying "You Only Store Text ... In Your DB", and store the image in a BLOB. But without more information than "It's the requirement of the project," it's hard to actually help.

Comment: @Phlip there are a plenty of reasons, including sharding, replication, fs limit, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're getting confused with how image uploading works with Rails (and especially with [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) / [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)). I'll explain how they work for you:

---

**You Only Store Text & References In Your DB (no Images)**

MYSQL & Rails only stores text in the DB, nothing else. The way the app works is to take the data inside the datatables & then link it with other code & assets in your app to make it work together

Paperclip & Carrierwave don't store the images in your DB; they store them in the `/public/system` folder of your Rails app (or on S3 if you want to put them there). They then link to the images by storing their name in the database. That's it

When you want to load the image (using Paperclip for example), you'll actually use ActiveRecord to load the contents of the `image` datatable, and Paperclip will create its own ActiveRecord object off the back of it

---

**Paperclip Or Carrierwave Will Help You**

You should check out [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip), it will help you a lot:
[image: RailsCast]

Answer (score 7):

You don't need `carrierwave` or `paperclip` upload gems to store images as blob.

Here is an example how to you can store an image in binary field (`raw_file`)

form:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
  # store uploaded avatar as blob
  @user.raw_file = params[:user][:avatar].read
  @user.save
end
```

Use [RMagick](http://studio.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#from_blob) or [mini_magick](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mini_magick/MiniMagick/Image#read-class_method) to convert image from blob.